# The evil genius infinite plan

Tags: mathematics, science

I'm an evil genius and I'll conquer the world with my minions :]
My minions have just 2 egdes but in just 2 minutes I've produced an infinite amount of them.
You'll see how I will conquer the world-
MUHAHAHAHAHA

How insane am I?

Comment: "egdes"- intentional or unintentional?

Comment: edges is a hint :) (intentional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm drawing a circle:

I'm an evil genius and I'll conquer the world with my minions :]
My minions have just 2 egdes but

> A Polygon consists of many triangles: when the count of the edges of the polygon goes to infinity
>  it becomes a circle while the infinite triangles are becoming twoangles

in just 2 minutes I've produced an infinite 
amount of them.

> Make a circle and color it

You'll see how I will conquer the world-
MUHAHAHAHAHA

How insane am I?

> really insane thinking of taking over the world with a circle

Answer (score 3):

I would say that

> You're not insane at all.

In two minutes, you can draw a

> Cylinder of any height. This cylinder has two curved edges (at the top and at the bottom. However, for any continuous cylinder of height $H$ there are an infinite number of subcylinders of height $h < H$. Your minions are therefore cylinders, and they are everywhere!!

Comment: nice, almost right, but have the subcylinders really just 2 edges? or do they have 1 universal edge, or even infinite? id even k

Comment: @Jannis: I would say that any subcylinder must have 2 edges (that's what makes it a cylinder), but there are an infinite number of them and some of the edges are shared....

Comment: I was thinking more 2 Dimensional

Answer (score 2):

Does this have to do with

> Mirrors?

The two edges would be

> The surface of the glass and
> The silver-painted back of the glass

An seemingly infinite number of them is created quickly by

> positioning them opposite one another, creating the [infinity mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_mirror) phenomenon. Your image is refelected and are your "minions."

You are indeed mad.

Comment: Thats a cool answer but thats not what i meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Speculative, but possibly:

> your minions are nothing!

I'm an evil genius and I'll conquer the world with my minions :]

> Obviously, any evil genius worth anything can conquer the world by themself.

My minions have just 2 egdes but in just 2 minutes I've prdouced an infinite amount of them.

> No shape has two edges, and you can't produce an infinite amount of anything in 2 minutes

You'll see how i will conquer the world-

> there's nothing after the hyphen

How insane are you?

> Not insane at all!

Alternatively, if you

> look at all the grammar mistakes

you get

> gdi, which means... god damn it? (wait no, the i got fixed)

Comment: The hyphen was just to connect the 'muhaha' with the 'conquer the world'. I hate too long rows, it looks optically not good. BUT somehow your is right

Comment: You're right with my minions are nothing and no shape has 2 edges, but your wrong with that